# Migrated content type fields not showing

Tags: migrations

I'm trying to migrate custom content types with attached fields from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8. Using drush migrate commands I can successfully migrate all content types, but I have problem with fields.

First I run *upgrade_d7_field* migration, than *upgrade_d7_field_instance* and last migration is *upgrade_d7_node_MY_CONTENT_TYPE_NAME_content*.

If I go to *Structure -> Content types* and then open my custom content type (by pressing *Manage fields*) I can see all fields attached to it - everything is ok. If I choose *Content* from main menu and try to create new content for my content type I only see Title field, no more fields are displayed. Same are with migrated content - if I 'm trying to edit it, I see only title.

What I'm missing ? I have migrated data in Drupal 8 fields table - node_field_*MY_FIELD_NAME*. I am logged in as admin user, so I should have all permissions to view this fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the fields might be disabled on the entity form.

Goto Structure -> YOUR CONTENT TYPE -> Manage form display

Then move the fields you are expecting to see in the form from **Disabled** (bottom) to **Content**.  You can also control the display order from there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a Drupal 8.9 site today. I went to Administration > Configuration > Content Authoring > Text formats and editors and clicked on Configure next to 'Full HTML.' That page showed an error that a null filter type would be deleted after I saved the current filter, so I clicked "Save" without making any other changes. The error was gone, and now my content is being displayed as expected.